# OpenCL generate error -32 on an intel system

Tags: visual-c++, opencl

I am trying to follow this tutorial on OpenCL:

https://anteru.net/2012/11/03/2009/

The code is as follow:

```
   // http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html
        cl_uint platformIdCount = 0;
        clGetPlatformIDs(0, nullptr, &platformIdCount);

        if (platformIdCount == 0) {
            std::cerr << "No OpenCL platform found" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Found " << platformIdCount << " platform(s)" << std::endl;
        }

        std::vector<cl_platform_id> platformIds(platformIdCount);
        clGetPlatformIDs(platformIdCount, platformIds.data(), nullptr);

        for (cl_uint i = 0; i < platformIdCount; ++i) {
            std::cout << "\t (" << (i + 1) << ") : " << GetPlatformName(platformIds[i]) << std::endl;
        }

        // http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html
        cl_uint deviceIdCount = 0;
        clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, nullptr,
            &deviceIdCount);

        if (deviceIdCount == 0) {
            std::cerr << "No OpenCL devices found" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Found " << deviceIdCount << " device(s)" << std::endl;
        }

        std::vector<cl_device_id> deviceIds(deviceIdCount);
        clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, deviceIdCount,
            deviceIds.data(), nullptr);

        for (cl_uint i = 0; i < deviceIdCount; ++i) {
            std::cout << "\t (" << (i + 1) << ") : " << GetDeviceName(deviceIds[i]) << std::endl;
        }

        // http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html
        const cl_context_properties contextProperties[] =
        {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, reinterpret_cast<cl_context_properties> (platformIds[0]),
            0, 0
        };

        cl_int error = CL_SUCCESS;
        cl_context context = clCreateContext(contextProperties, deviceIdCount,
            deviceIds.data(), nullptr, nullptr, &error);
        CheckError(error);
```

I am running it on an Intel i5 laptop. The output is as follow:

```
Found 2 platform(s)
         (1) : Experimental OpenCL 2.0 CPU Only Platform
         (2) : Intel(R) OpenCL
Found 1 device(s)
         (1) :        Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

the error code is -32

I am using visual studio 2013 on a windows 7 computer.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like when you try to create the context, you're using `platformIds[1]`, but the device you're passing belongs to `platformIds[0]`. Perhaps that could be a problem.

Comment: Error code -32 is in human readable form: `CL_INVALID_PLATFORM`.`

Comment: @brm I changed the code so that it points to platformIds[0], but I am still getting the same error. Please see updated code. Does my change fixed the problem that you mentioned?

Comment: Do you get the same error code? Have you tried using the other platform (so also getting the devices for that platform)?

Comment: @brm The error code is the same. How can I try to use other platform? I changed all 0 in platformIds[0] to 1 and get error code -33.

Comment: I think changing the platform id in both calls to `clGetDeviceIDs` and in the `contextProperties` should be all. Error -33 is CL_INVALID_DEVICE by the way (see https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.0/cl.h)

Comment: Did you install all the runtime drivers from Intel?  On some older iCore CPUs I've had to install the drivers listed on this page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

Comment: @Austin: It was driver problem and after I uninstall and reinstall all drivers and OpenCL library, it fixed the problem. Please make your comment to an answer and I will accept it as answer.

Comment: Will do, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the Intel OpenCL SDK doesn't have all the drivers, especially for older Xeon and iCore devices.  Intel does provide additional runtime installers for these devices, just not with the SDK.

Just Google: Intel OpenCL Runtime or [try this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) (valid as of 2-2-2015):